# Where does this function come from in this proof?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, elementary-set-theory, logic

This is an excerpt taken from a proof:

Let each $M_n(n\in\mathbb{N})$ be countable,

Then there exists an injective function $f_n:M_n\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$.

Now, set a function $k:\bigcup_nM_n\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ to be such that for each $a\in\bigcup_nM_n$,

$k(a)=\min\{j\mid a\in M_j\}$

Then the injection $f:\bigcup_nM_n\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is given by the following $f(a):=p_{k(a)}^{f_{k(a)}+1}$

where $p_{k(a)}$ is the $k(a)$-th prime number.

**Question**: I don't understand where this last identity for $f(a)$ comes from.

**My understanding** (or lack there of):

I feel comfortable understanding the domain $M_n$ and that each element is injectively mapped to an element in $\mathbb{N}$

I'm thinking of the function $k$ as a function that selects the first $M_j$ with $a$ in the domain.

So for $f(a)$ we map every $M_j$ up to $n$, but only from the function $f$ up to the first $M_j$ containing $a$

Becoming more confused the more I think about this...

Comment: Have you tried writing down explicit $M_j$s and $f_j$s in order to visualize what's going on? Also, that's not an identity for $f$, it's a definition.

Comment: Yes I have written out sets of elements for each $M_j$, should it be clear after writing it out? I think I'm probably getting confused with the $f$ function as opposed to the $k$ function or $M_j$ part

Comment: Are you confused about why $f$ is an injection, or where it comes from, or something else?

Comment: Where did they come up with the identity: $f(a):=p_{k(a)}^{f_{k(a)+1}}$, could this be broken down into more steps to arrive at this identity

Comment: I told you, it's not an identity, it's a definition.

Comment: Oh, where is that definition from?

Comment: It's from the proof. What you cited is them giving you the definition of an injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an illustration. Suppose

$$M_1=\{1\} \quad M_2=\{2,3\} \quad M_3=\{4,5,6\} \quad M_4=\{7,8,9,10\} \quad \cdots $$

and

$$\begin{array}{llll} M_1\to\Bbb N: & \color{Red}{f_1(1)=0} \\ M_2\to\Bbb N: & \color{Purple}{f_2(2)=0} & \color{Purple}{f_2(3)=1} \\ M_3\to\Bbb N: & \color{Blue}{f_3(4)=0} & \color{Blue}{f_3(5)=1} & \color{Blue}{f_3(6)=2} \\ M_4\to\Bbb N: & \color{Green}{f_4(7)=0} & \color{Green}{f_4(8)=1} & \color{Green}{f_4(9)=2} & \color{Green}{f_4(10)=3} \\ \cdots \end{array} $$

Then

$$\begin{array}{r} \color{Red}{f(1)=2^1} \\ \color{Purple}{f(2)=3^1} \\ \color{Purple}{f(3)=3^2} \\ \color{Blue}{f(4)=5^1} \\ \color{Blue}{f(5)=5^2} \\ \color{Blue}{f(6)=5^3} \\ \color{Green}{f(7)=7^1} \\ \color{Green}{f(8)=7^2} \\ \color{Green}{f(9)=7^3} \\ \color{Green}{f(10)=7^4} \end{array} $$

Thus, the prime number base of $f(a)$ tracks which $M_j$ an $a$ is in, and the exponent indicates which element of $M_j$ it is. This fact about how $f$ works is true no matter what the individual sets $M_1,M_2,M_3,\cdots$s are (they could even be infinite) or what the $f_1,f_2,f_3,\cdots$s are, although clearly by changing those sets and functions you do change the function $f$.

*Inspiration*. Prime factorization is essentially a map from $\Bbb N^{\oplus\Bbb N}$ (natural number-indexed sequences of natural numbers with all but finitely many coordinates zero) to $\Bbb N$ given by

$$(e_0,e_1,e_2,\cdots)\mapsto 2^{e_0}3^{e_1}5^{e_2}\cdots $$

In order to construct the map $\bigcup M_j\to\Bbb N$ from the $f_j$, we just need to use $f_j$ to embed $M_j$ into the $j$th coordinate of $\Bbb N^{\oplus\Bbb N}$ and then use the above map.